# How to find out if azure vm has KEK or BEK Encryption?

Tags: azure, bitlocker

Is there nay powershell command by using which I can find out if the VM is KEK encrypted or BEK encrypted?

Also can I move a VM after decrypting it across subscription?

Answer (score 0):

Via powerhshell you can check the encryption status. It will only say whether the OS and data volumes are encrypted or not. [sample](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/security/quick-encrypt-vm-powershell.md)

After decrypting I believe the movement should not be an issue though I have not tried it out personally. 
Also there are [ways](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/8684) to move an encrypted VM to another subscription.

Comment: he is not asking for that?